# Выбрать данные из SQLite за последние 24 часа

Tags: java, android

Необходимо получить данные из базы SQLite за последние 24 часа. В базе одна таблица с 3-мя колонками(широта, долгота и время). Время определяю через Calendar:

```
Calendar addTimeCalendar;
public String getAddTime() {
    addTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return addTime = String.valueOf(addTimeCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Затем записываю в базу:

```
public void addCoordinates() {
    SQL sqlHelper = new SQL(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in coordinates: ---");
    cv.put("Latitude", latitude);
    cv.put("Longitude", longitude);
    cv.put("Time", getAddTime());
    long rowID = db.insert("coordinates", null, cv);
    db.close();
    sqlHelper.close();
}
```

Была идея брать текущее время через второй Calendar, вычитать от него то время, когда происходила запись БД, а потом через запрос выводить данные по дате, которые меньше этой разницы (текущее время - время записи в БД). Как это реализовать? Или можно как-то попроще?

Comment: в запросе используйте выборку по больше,чем  datetime('now','localtime') - 24 часа

Comment: в `datetime` еще [модификаторы](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions) есть, можно их использовать, например `start of day`

Comment: т.е. использовать 1 календарь, а потом в запросе по выборке что-то на подобии этого использовать:

    SELECT datetime('now', 'start of day' - '1 day')

Comment: да, что то вроде того

Comment: а зачем в getAddTime вот эта строчка  ? : addTimeCalendar.setTimeInMillis(1111111111111L);

Comment: забыл ее убрать, уже убрал )

Comment: в каком формате получать дату/время через Calendar?

Comment: Потому что разницы между

    SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE datetime('now', 'start of day', '-1 day')

и

    SELECT * FROM coordinates

нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слишком мудрите - надо проще, примерно так:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
long dayAgo=System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60*1000; //day ago
Cursor cursor=db.query("mytable", new String[] {"Latitude", "Longitude", "Time"}, "Time >="+dayAgo, null, null, "time");
while(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
   //blah-blah
}
```

Писал на коленках, так что возможно всякие *typo* - я же не компилятор таки ))

Comment: ругается на query, что cannot resolve method query

Comment: я почему то верую, что БД нужна не только для хранения, но и для обработки хранимых данных - пусть сама делает выборку по нужным условиям, ни к чему за нее вычислять, когда было вчера :)

Comment: Я бы правда вместо System.currentTimeMillis() использовал Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()  так как в базу данных автор так же с календаря записыват дату и время. Разница будет так как системное время не учитывает региональные установки на устройстве.